# What kind of model/loss function for unknown categories to predict value?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking to predict the sales of a given customer based on 1) previous history, 2) some subclass information and 3) arbitrary month information. Month might be an influence for some customers but not others. Information would look roughly like so:

```
account_id  sub_account month sales
3           1           12    90
3           1           1     120
3           2           12    100
3           2           1     50
1           1           12    20
1           1           12    50
1           1           12    300
1           3           12    50
```

So, while I could use some type of encoding, I'm not sure what matters and what doesn't. It "feels like" some type of unsupervised clustering around values, but not sure what the best way to approach this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a supervised learning (a regression problem, because your target variable is continuous). Also, as you happen to have the previous history of the customer, you are really in front of a *time series* forecasting problem.

There are many (many...) different ways of addressing this, but an easy (and quite effective) one is to solve the problem using [autoregression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model):

- Choose a `window_size` (number of months to look back - e.g 5)
- For each pair (account_id, sub_account) and set of `window_size` consecutive months, generate:
  `sales_5m_ago, sales_4m_ago, ... ,sales_1m_ago ==> sales this month`
  as a training instance.

In this way, you will end up with a dataset with many subsets of sales history that can be used to predict what would happen in the following month. Then, you can build any regression model with it (e.g. a RandomForestRegressor) and to forecast the sales of test customers you'll only need to provide the previous `window_size` sales, and the model will give you the prediction for the next month.

Finally, if you want/have additional features in your original data, you can just group them together with your monthly sales values when creating your training set:

`sales_5m_ago, sales_4m_ago, ...` ==> 
`sales_5m_ago,temperature_5m_ago, rain_days_5m_ago, sales_4m_ago,temperature_4m_ago, rain_days_4m_ago, ...`

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, it's probably the right one given what I asked. I wanted to emphasize moreso that the sales # isn't influenced by the *actual* date at all, but I didn't do a good job of that. However, the point *is* to tie it to previous results, and I think that's the larger point and I think you've address coming up with groups, though I'm going to dig into it deeper.

This example was a stand-in -- a different way might have emphasized the lack of relationship between "dateime" and result: an example for predicting HTTP response time for example. Anyway, thank you!